# Non-Jewish relatives

Tags: halacha

How do you treat relatives whom are not jewish, ie Grandmothers and so on.

Can one benefit anything from them, as in being mentioned in a will…

Answer (score -1):

"How do you treat relatives whom are not jewish, ie Grandmothers and so on."

You treat her like your grandmother.

And if you're in Boston, then maybe you can sign her up for this class so she can understand you better: https://www.jewishboston.com/read/your-grandkids-are-jewish-youre-not-now-what/

Comment: Though, they are not considered your relatives or anything of that sort. So you treat her like a regular persone or like an actual relative. 

And can you benefit from them?

Comment: There's a big difference between understanding the implications of them not being Jewish, and deciding they are "not your relatives." You would be advised to not trust her kashrut in cooking, and you wouldn't be required to sit shiv'a. This has more to do with understanding they will not understand the rules we as Jews are bound by. And yes a convert is considered to no longer "be the child of their original family." But that has more to do with ensuring we treat such converts as full Jews.